# Mono runtime version supported by this application is unavailable

Tags: c#, android, windows, mono

I am trying to convert an old application made for window CE in C#(build with visual studio 2008 framework 3.5) with last version of mono and it gives me the following error:
Somebodies can help me please?

`````
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\Temp\ChargOc.exe
AOTID 2AAD333E-6B6F-7B55-A6EA-0A45EDE196B9
Failed to load method 0x60000e4 from 'C:\Temp\ChargOc.exe' due to Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies..
Run with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug for more information.
AOT of image C:\Temp\ChargOc.exe failed ````

Many thanks in advances,
`````

Comment: What output did you get when you ran: Run with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug ?

Comment: Mono is not designed to run .NET Compact Framework apps/assemblies. If you want to port to Mono, you need to do that at source code level. Also in 2021, you should migrate any code to .NET Core/.NET 5, as Mono is being phased out.